# Ensure array isn't empty when looping with ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I need to display data from an array in a table. What condition can I use to ensure that the array should not be iterated when it is empty?

```
<tr *ngFor="let something of (adunit.unit_price)">
<td>{{something.updated_date | date : 'medium' }}</td>
<td>{{ something.value }}</td>
```

Comment: It won't iterate by default if it is empty. You don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an Elvis operator which will check for the existence of the parent variable first. Like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let something of adunit?.unit_price">
<td>{{something.updated_date | date : 'medium' }}</td>
<td>{{ something.value }}</td>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap your table inside an `*ngIf`

```
<table *ngIf="adunit.unit_price.length">
  <tr *ngFor="let something of (adunit.unit_price)">
  <td>{{something.updated_date | date : 'medium' }}</td>
  <td>{{ something.value }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Probably not a `div` element though, given you are wrapping rows. Perhaps on the `table` or `tbody`?

Comment: @Fenton true, modified

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about iteration, as Angular will take care of it for you. If array is empty, it won't iterate.